# method with multiple class implementing same interface

Tags: java, java-8

I have an interface :

```java
public interface I {
   getBar();
}
```

I have 2 class : `A` and `B` implementing `I`.

What I want to do is :

```java
public void foo(List<I> items) {
   for (I item : items){
      if (item instanceof A) this.append((A) item);
      if (item instanceof B) this.append((B) item);
   }
}
```

Is there something as of java 8 that would allow me to not have that list of `instanceof` and call it like this ?

```java
items.foreach(this::append);
```

---

**Note :**
I could do something like `item.add(this)` which would append itself to `this` but then I would call a method on an object that modifies the parameter (and only it) but this is bad practice as stated by Robert C. Martin's "Clean Code" :

> Arguments are most naturally interpreted as inputs to a function.
>
> Anything that forces you to check the function signature is equivalent to a double-take. It’s a cognitive break and should be avoided. In the days before object oriented programming it was sometimes necessary to have output arguments. However, much of the need for output arguments disappears in OO languages

Comment: Why do you have `append(A)` and `append(B)` at all? The design looks quite *iffy* to begin with.

Comment: Imo the method should be `append(I)` and then inside of it you perform different things based on type.

Comment: @Kayaman : To be short, I am appending line of a flat file with tons of rules to an object. ILine is the interface. Each line is an object of A or B (or C,D,E...). @Amongalen : change `append(I)` to `add(I)` and you have what's in the note.

Comment: does `append(A)` and `append(B)` much different?

Comment: @user902383 Yes.

Answer (score 1):

just move the instanceof stuff to a generic append func

```
private void append(I item) {
  if (item instanceof A) ...
  if (item instanceof B) ...
}
```

then you can use

```
items.foreach(this::append);
```

Comment: It is what I ended doing did but it is not that different. I still have that list of `isntanceof`. I will edit my question to be more clear about that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Degravef and you'll have those around because of your design. Now you're just playing with where to put them. To get rid of them fully, you would need a bigger design change.

Comment: I took this project from an ex-coworker. He made the `spring batch reader` return a list of ILine's consisting of differents objects of class implementing ILine. I found it weird from the time I saw it but he usually did a good job and was more experienced than I am so I kept it. Now deadline is too close to change it. I will go with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

what if you take more  OOP approach,

1. define Appender

> ```
> interface Appender{
>   void append(I item);
> }
> ```

2. create your appenders for A B and default appender that do nothing
3. put appenders into map Map<Class,Appender>
4. change your code to

> ```
>  for (I item : items){
>      appenders.getOrDefault(item.class,DEFAULT_APPENDER).append(item);
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about it upside down.

Your class gets these instances of `I` and has a different overloaded method based on the type. This overload means it needs to be aware of all implementations, to provide a different overload for each.

The problem, obviously, is that the list must grow as implementations are added.

The solution is to make the **implementations** of `I` responsible for knowing how they are appended.

```
public interface I {
    Bar getBar(); /* you missed the return type, but anyway */

    void appendTo(SomeType foo);
}
```

Your method simply becomes

```
public void foo(List<I> items) {
   for (I item : items){
      item.appendTo(this); //or instead of this, some append-able instance 
   }
}
```

If someone adds a new implementation of `I`, they are forced to write an append method as part of the interface's contract.

Answer (score 0):

Actual answer: This is a double-dispatch problem and the Java-centric solution is the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) which is quite a lot of change.

Silly answer: Just for kicks, there's no `instanceof` *here*:

```java
    private static final Map<Class<?>, Consumer<I>> DISPATCHER = Map.of(
      A.class, this::appendA,
      B.class, this::appendB
    );

    items.forEach(i -> DISPATCHER.get(i.getClass()).accept());
```

Yeah, it's still branchy and must run many more instructions to get the same result :)